# array of function declaration and assignment problem

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to create an array of pointers to functions, and trying to assign the function address to it. But i am getting errors which i dont know how to proceed with.

My code

```
void (*Event_Handlers)[3]();  //Line no 10

/* Queue, Drop and Send_back have been defined. for eg */
void Queue()
{
....
}

Event_Handlers[0]=Queue;  // Line 35
Event_Handlers[1]=Drop;   // Line 36
Event_Handlers[2]=Send_Back;   // Line 37
```

But i am getting the following error

```
 fsm.c:10: error: declaration of âEvent_Handlersâ as array of functions

 fsm.c:35: warning: data definition has no type or storage class

 fsm.c:35: error: invalid initializer

 fsm.c:36: warning: data definition has no type or storage class

 fsm.c:36: error: invalid initializer

 fsm.c:37: warning: data definition has no type or storage class

 fsm.c:37: error: invalid initializer
```

Where am in going wrong

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are very close...

Try:

```
void (*Event_Handlers[3])();
```

Comment: thank you Nemo.. But still the warning persists.. wat may be the reason?

Comment: Seriously?  What compiler?  I tried your version (and got the warning) then mine (and it went away).  I just tried it again to make sure...  Try @Mihran's approach; it is clearer anyway.

Comment: My version is gcc. I tried Mihrans approach. Still i am getting that error

Comment: I assume the warning on line 10 is gone?  Are you trying to put these assignments at the top level?  You cannot have code outside of a function in C...  You have to put them into a function (say, main())

Comment: @CHID: Have you tried using proper prototypes? `void Queue(void)` and `void (*Event_Handlers[3])(void)`? Your compiler could be slipping into K&R mode and getting confused. And yeah, Mihran's typedef (an awesome band name BTW) approach will be less confusing in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

For first time to be sure that you declared array of pointers to function use the following syntax:

```
typedef void (*func_t)();
func_t EventHandlers[3];
```

Comment: thankk you Mihran. I tried ur code. But still my compiler complains.. Now i get a new error. "Conflictng types of EventHandlers followed by invalid initialiser". My code contains only the above mentioned lines. I have made sure that ther is no otherp ointer by the name EventHandlers

Comment: What compiler do you use? Are you sure there is no `EventHandlers` variable in other place in your code (try `grep -r 'EventHandlers' ./` through all source files). Try to initialize EventHandlers after declaration (`func_t EventHandlers[3] = {NULL}`).

Comment: Thank you Mihran. The problem was solved. #Nemo's second comment

Answer (score 0):

the array element type could be function pointer, but can not be function.

void (* Event_Handlers[3])()

will be the right answer